# How to define a null element in simpleframework

Tags: simple-framework

i am very new to simpleframework 
This is my xml file:

```
<Resource>
  <attribute>
    <vegetable>
    <fruit xsi:nil="true"/>
    <flowers>
  </attribute>
</Resource>
```

and my annotated java class using simple framework is as follows:
Resource.java

```
    @Root (name="Resource")
public static class Attribute {

    @Element(required=false)
    public String vegetable;
    @Element( required=false)
    public String fruit;
    @Attribute (name="xsi:nil",  required=false)
            ---
    @Element(required=false)
    public String flowers;

  }
```

i am not sure what to write in the Attribute to as to make fruit value as null. Can anyone help me with it?